# Design issues concerning image upload in Android app

Tags: android

This one is for the Android specialists.
I'm very new to android and I find myself very uncertain on many design issues which I assume are very common in mobile development.
I would like your opinion on the best practice of doing several things (and perhaps - how).

Background information: In my application the user is supposed to take a photo and then both save it for local use and also upload it to a server so that others would consume it through different devices (different resolutions, tablets, etc.).

My questions are:

1. I understand that I need to save the image in different resolutions, should I have the user's device perform these expensive tasks of adjusting the image into a 3-4 different resolutions and then upload them to a server? or should I just upload the image and then have the server work like crazy on those photos?
2. Something more technical. I need to upload the image to the server and then continue with the id that the server gave that image. Hence, I MUST wait for the server's response which might take quite some time. Until then I can not continue, how can I avoid ANR?

Please advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **1.** Better to upload the image to the server and then server will do the rest of resolution management tasks.

For **2.** Upload the image with a `Unique_id_from_device` and from the server send a notification to the device against the `Unique_id_from_device` with the `message/response` that you want to receive, or from the device check for the response via an async task.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm wondering if it's not wise to have the user's device work a little and resize images once in a while than to have the server work hard on hundreds of pictures, which will result in expenses on more servers or slow reaction from server. Any pro and cons about that?

Comment: instead of multiple image upload, upload an image to the server and then save with different resolution in the server, that's actually done everywhere.